# Recursive function type

Tags: rust

In [Rob Pike's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxaD_trXwRE#t=855) on lexical scanning in Go, he defines a function type `stateFn` which returns another `stateFn`, like so:

```
type stateFn func() stateFn
```

In an attempt to do something similar in Rust, I tried this:

```
type stateFn = fn() -> stateFn;
```

but the compiler complains "illegal recursive type; insert an enum or struct in the cycle, if this is desired".

Can I do this in Rust, and if so, how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can wrap the function type in a nominal type (i.e. a struct or enum). This is actually what the Go code is doing: `type T U` defines a new, distinct type `T` that's not directly interchangable with `U`, while Rust's `type` is just an alias, like `type` in Haskell and `typedef` in C.

So, one might write:

```
struct StateFn(fn() -> Option<StateFn>);
```

or

```
struct StateFn {
    f: fn() -> Option<StateFn>
}
```

(I've had to add the `Option` because Go's `func` can be nil, while Rust removes nullability by default, making it opt-in.)

That said, I suspect that `func` is a closure in Go (can store some internal state), while `fn` in Rust is just a function pointer (no state at all), so you may wish to use a closure in Rust too. One might do this by replacing `fn() -> Option<StateFn>` with a `Box<Fn() -> Option<StateFn>>`, and creating it with `Box::new(move || { /* code here */ })`.

One might also use [`FnMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) instead of `Fn` which gives you more flexibility, or even [`FnOnce`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) which represents a closure that can only be called once. Each of these places successively more restrictions on the caller, but gives the closure itself successively more flexibility. (However, "object safety" concerns mean that `Box<FnOnce>` doesn't work at the moment, ["Purging proc"](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/11/26/purging-proc/) has more details and a work-around.)

```
struct StateFn {
    f: Box<FnMut() -> Option<StateFn>>
}
```

The parsing loop for any of these situations might look like:

```
let mut state_fn = Some(initial_fn);
while let Some(mut f) = state_fn {
    state_fn = (*f.f)()
}
```

Comment: Fn places the most restrictions on the caller (must not mutate the environment) and FnOnce can even consume/move the environment. FnOnce is implemented for FnMut and FnMut is implemented for Fn. I think FnOnce fits best here.

Comment: No, the *caller* has the least restrictions for `Fn`: e.g. they can call it through a `&Fn()`, but neither `FnMut` or `FnOnce` can be called there, while `FnOnce` has to be called by-value and can only be called once (which is much more restrictive). On the otherhand, `Fn` places the most restrictions on the *callee* (the closure itself), while `FnOnce` is the least restrictive for the closure (that is the body of a `FnOnce` closure has the most flexibility). As the answer describes, `FnOnce` is the best, but there's some subtleties around trait objects that mean it doesn't work directly.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I thought of a function that takes a FnOnce/FnMut/Fn as argument.