# c++ recursive function type

Tags: c++, recursion

Rob Pike made a talk in 2011 ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxaD_trXwRE#t=855)) about lexers in go,
where he defined a type like this:

```
// stateFn represents the state of the scanner
// as a function that returns the next state.
type stateFn func() stateFn
```

I want to achieve the same in C++, but can't figure out how:

```cpp
// 01: error C3861: 'statefn_t': identifier not found
typedef std::function<statefn_t()> statefn_t;

// 02: error C2371: 'statefn_t': redefinition; different basic types
typedef std::function<class statefn_t()> statefn_t;

// 03: error C2371: 'statefn_t': redefinition; different basic types
typedef std::function<struct statefn_t()> statefn_t;

// 04: error C2065: 'statefn_t': undeclared identifier
typedef std::function<statefn_t*()> statefn_t;

// 05: error C2371: 'statefn_t': redefinition; different basic types
typedef std::function<class statefn_t*()> statefn_t;

// 06: error C2371: 'statefn_t': redefinition; different basic types
typedef std::function<struct statefn_t*()> statefn_t;
```

*Note: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886474/recursive-function-type) question might be connected (it's the same in Rust)*

**Edit:**

Here is what i am trying to achieve:

```cpp
// statefn_t definition goes here ...

statefn_t* func1()
{
    return &func2;
}

statefn_t* func2()
{
    return &func1;
}
```

Comment: Could you use a class that overloads `operator ()`?

Comment: I see no definition for statefn_t, looks like like compiler can't see it either.

Comment: @SergeyA The OP's idea is to define it in that very typedef - a recursive type.

Comment: Can you describe how you would use this type in C++. For now, lacking such clarification, I'm voting to close this as unclear.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf • it would be used by `state = state(context);` where state is the next state after processing the current context.  The state variable is a `state_t state(context_t&)` where `state_t` is defined as `state_t (*state_t)(context_t&);` ... which can't be expressed in C++ as a function returning a function of the same signature.  But having a polymorphic type can do it in C++.

Comment: It's a variation / duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809304/how-to-write-a-function-pointer-to-a-function-returning-a-function-pointer-to-a .

Comment: Then you can use a struct containing a function pointer (for assignment) and an `operator()`. No big deal technically, but for C++ it's more like obfuscation than a natural way to go about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type aliases cannot be recursive.

To achieve a state machine such as the one used in the go lecture, you will need to define a custom type:

```
class state
{
public:
    using fn = std::function<state()>;
    state() {}
    state(fn f) : f(f){}
    operator bool() { return (bool)f; }
    operator fn () { return f; }

private:
    fn f;
};
```

Usage:

```
state::fn stateEnd()
{
    std::cout << "end\n";
    return {};
}
state::fn stateTransit()
{
    std::cout << "transit\n";
    return stateEnd;
}

state::fn stateStart()
{
    std::cout << "start\n";
    return stateTransit;
}


int main() {
    state::fn s = stateStart;
    while(s = s());
}
```

---

Alternative form:

```
class state
{
public:
    state() {}
    template<class T>
    state(T&& t) : f(std::forward<T>(t)){}
    operator bool() { return (bool)f; }
    state operator()() { return f(); }

private:
    std::function<state()> f;
};
```

Usage:

```
state stateEnd()
{
    std::cout << "end\n";
    return {};
}
state stateTransit()
{
    std::cout << "transit\n";
    return stateEnd;
}

state stateStart()
{
    std::cout << "start\n";
    return stateTransit;
}


int main() {
    state s {stateStart};
    while(s = s());
}
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Mostly because I couldn't figure out how to do the original form without `std::function`. That said, when using `std::function`, the state function can contain *state* i.e. it can be a capturing lambda or whatever. I wouldn't know whether that is needed. If it's not needed, then the alternative form can be trivially transformed to use a function pointer at which point it is fairly similar to your suggestion.

Comment: struct state : public std::function<state()> {
        using base = std::function<state()>;
        using base::base;
   };

Answer (score 1):

As Clearer commented, here is an example of a C++ type `stateFn` that behaves like a function and recursively returns an instance of the same type.

```
struct stateFn
{
    stateFn& operator() ();
}
```

Comment: Since this would be totally without value I suspect you have completely misunderstood what the OP is after. I would guess it's more like an abstract stack type or something.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `operator()` could easily be made virtual (probably pure virtual) so derived types can override it. This is a type of [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

Comment: @Kevin: The OP's envisioned usage is via assignment, which slices. Which means you need some more machinery than just virtual functions, in order to go that route. And with that machinery it's no point in having the virtual functions.

Comment: **−1** To counter the silly upvotes. This is not an answer. It's totally without value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the recursion to be resolved at runtime, while keeping it as similar as possible to your original code, you may use boost::any or C++17 std::any, something like:

```
std::any end(){ std::cout << "end\n"; return {}; }
std::any state(){ std::cout << "some state\n"; return &end; }
std::any begin(){ std::cout << "begin\n"; return &state; }

void advance( std::any& state )
    { state = std::any_cast<std::any(*)()>(state)(); }

int main()
{
    for( auto state = begin(); state.has_value(); advance( state ) );
}
```

---

If the recursion has to be resolved at compile time, you may exploit auto type deduction:

```
auto end(){ std::cout << "end\n"; }
auto state(){ std::cout << "some state\n"; return &end; }
auto begin(){ std::cout << "begin\n"; return &state; }

int main()
{
    begin()()();
}
```

of course, this won't work within loops, you need some kind of compile time iteration scheme in order for this to be useful ...

Comment: Did you check if that compiles if you add back the omitted includes? If it compiles then it would be very interesting to know which compiler and the exact invocation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf here is a [live compile](https://godbolt.org/g/C3F1vU), it compiles on both latest gcc and clang; the equivalent boost::any code is ok as well; why do you believe it should not ? anyway, edited the declaration order to make things more explicit ...

Comment: The new declaration order can compile, yes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a natural way to do things in C++.

In C++ it's more like obfuscation, which is reflected in the difficulty of finding good self-describing names for the state advancing functions that also are states:

```
struct Context {};

class State
{
    using F = auto( Context const& ) -> State;
    F* next_state_;

public:
    auto is_finished() const -> bool { return next_state_ == nullptr; }

    auto operator()( Context const& ctx ) const
        -> State
    { return next_state_( ctx ); }

    State( F* f ): next_state_{ f } {}
    inline State();
};

auto intermediate( Context const& ) { return State{ nullptr }; }
auto start( Context const& ) { return State{ intermediate }; }

State::State(): next_state_{ start } {}

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    State       state;
    Context     ctx;

    cout << boolalpha;
    for( ;; )
    {
        cout << state.is_finished() << endl;
        if( state.is_finished() ) { break; }
        state = state( ctx );
    }
}
```

Comment: @SergeyA: How come you think that? It's standard C++ syntax, and conforms to Herb Sutter's [“almost always auto”](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) advice. Are you unfamiliar with the ordinary C++ syntax? Are you envisioning this code being scrutinized by beginners using Bad Teaching Materials™ that don't teach them the syntax? If so, how about, say, the `boolalpha`, or the `for(;;)`?

Comment: I love boolapha, and for(;;) is ok, though people tend to do `while (true)`. However, `auto main() -> int` is more characters than `int main()`, it has a bad syntax (as is prescribed in C++ standard), it doesn't really improve readability (`auto` in return type is good for cases when type is deduced, but in your case it is plain int). I just see no need for it here.

Comment: @SergeyA: I understand. The argument "it has a bad syntax" is impossible to refute on rational grounds.

Comment: Well, as is with all 'good' and 'bad' it is usually just the conforming opinion. I would doubt anybody would say it is a good syntax. A lot of people (myself included) will agree that it is a least evil all things considered, by I am 100% certain nobody would go for it if we would be developing language from the scratch without all the limitations we have currently. So while I am certainly fine with using it when needed (although I prefer auto type deduction from return statement, which you can't use for main in your example), I think it should be used wisely.

Comment: @SergeyA: I guess you didn't notice the self-contradiction when you wrote “I love `boolapha`, and `for(;;)` is ok, though people tend to do `while (true)`. However, `auto main() -> int` is more characters than `int main()`”. The `while(true)` that your recommend on conforming-to-the-herd grounds is more characters than `for(;;)` (with older compilers it also tends to produce sillywarnings). So the argument for `int main`, fewer characters, doesn't apply to that case. I know that we're into irrational group psychology here. I just wanted to point it out to you that that's where we are at.

Comment: Well, number of characters is not the only factor, not even the most important one. But it attributes to signal-to-noise ratio (on the noise side), so all other things being equal, less characters are usually better option. With endless loops, `while (true)` in my view is more explicit, but even more important, is more idiomatic. But the difference between two is insignificant, and I would not even mention that. Mandatory disclosure: did not downvote :)